# Why does renvoyer mean to UNemploy? Where is employer sending the sacked employee?

Tags: étymologie

Renvoyer means to send back. But back to where?

I am baffled because the employer dismissed the employee. So the employer is no longer authorized to send the employee any where!

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/renvoyer

> De *[envoyer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/envoyer)*, avec le préfixe [r-](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r-).

https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/renvoyer

> **Étymol. et Hist. 1. a)** *Ca* 1160 « faire retourner (quelqu'un) là où il était précédemment » (*Enéas*, éd. J. J. Salverda de Grave, 6250: mort li **renveoit** Eneas); **b)** *ca* 1200 « démobiliser, licencier, congédier » (Jean Bodel, *Saxons*, éd. F. Menzel et E. Stengel, 284: il departi ses oz, s'en **ranvoia** sa gent); 1480 (*Lettre de Marguerite de Bourgogne*, 14 sept. ds *Mém. de Ph. de Comines, Preuves*, éd. Lenglet du Fresnoy, t. 3, 1747, pp. 606-607: avez fait casser et **renvoyer** par-deça trois ou quatre cens Archers); **c)** 1569 « faire repartir, éconduire (quelqu'un) » (Ronsard, *Œuvres compl.*, éd. P. Laumonier, t. 15, p. 171, 85: le debteur **r'envoye**); **d)** 1665 dr. « déclarer non coupable, acquitter » (La Fontaine, *Imitation des Arrêts d'Amours* ds *Œuvres*, éd. H. Régnier, t. 8, p. 424: la cour [...] la **renvoya**);

> #### envoy (n.) [[on Etymonline]](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=envoy)
>
> "messenger," 1660s, from French *envoyé* "messenger; a message; a sending; the postscript of a poem," literally "one sent" (12c.), noun use of past participle of envoyer "send,"
> from Vulgar Latin **inviare* "send on one's way,"
> from Latin *in* "on" (from PIE root [*en](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*en?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "in")    + via "road" (see [via](https://www.etymonline.com/word/via?ref=etymonline_crossreference) (adv.)).
> The same French word was borrowed in Middle English as envoi in the sense "stanza of a poem 'sending it off' to find readers" (late 14c.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sent back to whatever place the employee was before being employed. <s>It's kind of a metaphor, the employer is not sending the laid off employee to any particular place.</s> See Gilles' answer for what location it used to be.

This is not unlike the English metaphor *to fire someone* where the employee is hopefully not blasted out of a cannon...

Answer (score 5):

The employee is sent back home. The etymology suggests that the word was originally used for soldiers, who live out of home while they are on a military campaign. If they are dismissed, they presumably travel back to their home.

Comment: Right: *renvoyé dans ses foyers*.